# Sniffed packets are wrong

Tags: c#, packet-capture, sniffing

I want to sniff packets on my server and I just tried some wrappers for receive packets like MJSniffer, SharpCap but thats all show me wrong data

I had to write server - client exe for check received packets and im surprised. For example i sent to following packet

```
client_.Send(new byte[] { 0x01 , 0xC1 , 0x12 });
```

and following packets received by sniffer, and its often show different bytes.I tried to convert them to hex value's and same result

```
136, 184, 7, 50, 226, 41, 144, 15, 202, 11, 76, 178, 80, 16, 1, 0, 18, 142, 0, 0
```

what does it mean ? can i receive like 0x01 0xC1 0x12

Sniff code :

```
   public void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int nReceived = this._SocketCnn.EndReceive(ar);
        ParseData(byteData, nReceived);
        byteData = new byte[4096];
        this._SocketCnn.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
    }

    public void ParseData(byte[] byteData, int nReceived)
    {

        IPHeader ipHeader = new IPHeader(byteData, nReceived);
        if (ipHeader.ProtocolType == Protocol.TCP)
        {
            TCPHeader tcpHeader = new TCPHeader(ipHeader.Data, (int)ipHeader.MessageLength);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(tcpHeader.SourcePort) == this._ParamsCnn.Port)
            {
                TCPHeader tcpHeader_ = new TCPHeader(byteData, nReceived);
                ReturnData returnMsg_ = new ReturnData();
                returnMsg_.ReceivedData = ipHeader.Data;
                returnMsg_.SourceIPAddress = ipHeader.SourceAddress.ToString();
                returnMsg_.SourcePort = Convert.ToInt32(tcpHeader.SourcePort);
                returnMsg_.TargetIPAddress = ipHeader.DestinationAddress.ToString();
                returnMsg_.TargetPort = Convert.ToInt32(tcpHeader.DestinationPort);
                OnDataReceivedEvent(returnMsg_);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you expect your sniffer to deliver only TCP payloads, not raw packets?

Comment: i sent 0x01 , 0xC1 , 0x12 TCP packets but sniffer capture it as  136, 184, 7, 50, 226, 41,......

Comment: Yup, you said that already. Are you sure the sniffer is not dumping the raw IP packets? Can you post the parts of your code that performs the capture?

Comment: TCP has headers on it you need to account for. Sniffers like wireshark, you will need to look specifically at the data portion of the packet.

Comment: code added i checked tcpHeader.Data but its empty